Did they change something in "Privacy & Security" in MacOS 15 and above?
I'm having the output of systemextensionsctl list of Cisco Secure Client - Socket Filter Extension as [activated waiting for user] and getting the "Action Required" window telling me to open Privacy & Security and allow the System Extension. However when I go there, the option to allow is not there.
We haven't changed anything in our MDM and the TeamIdentifier seems to be the same, and the <key>AllowedUserOverrides</key> is set to <true/> which seemed to be working as expected in earlier versions of MacOS and it made me wonder if they've changed something in the new version that needs us to modify something in our .mobileconfig file or what else is there to do.

There have certainly been changes to Priv & Sec in Sequoia (15), which is the latest version of macOS -- based on the fact that there are more "Allow/Deny" hoops to jump through for the user than on Sonoma (which itself had more than the previous). But what the technical details are, I can't say.

Have you tried General: Device Management?
